# Dynamically changing -line-clamp

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm enlarging an element and attempting to change the `-webkit-line-clamp`. It works in that it shows the right amount of lines after the change, but it doesn't work in that the ellipsis and link (after text) don't move to the (new) end.

View [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdNBga)

If you click the "Make it Big" button, you'll see what I mean.

How Can I make it so that the ellipsis and link get pushed to the end after changing the `-webkit-line-clamp`?

HTML:

```
<div class="api-family-tile-description">
  A bunch of text <a href="/someplace">View&nbsp;more&nbsp;&gt;</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.api-family-tile-description {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  height: 108px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

JS:

```
var lineheight = 18;
var lines = 14;
$(".api-family-tile-description").css({
    height: (lineheight*lines)+"px",
    "-webkit-line-clamp": lines
});
```

Comment: Here's how to change `line-clamp` dynamically - https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/QNxeVQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this — http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/ZGOEdz:

```
$(".api-family-tile-description").css({
    height: (lineheight*lines)+"px",
    "-webkit-line-clamp": lines.toString()
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/css/:

> When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a
>   string and add px to the end of that string. If the property requires
>   units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the
>   appropriate units before calling the method.

Comment: It's interesting that it partially works without conversion to string (it will clamp to however many lines you put in)... just with some issues... anyway, thanks.